# In k means elbow method how do we define the axis from the data set for sum of squared axis?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I m new to data science, and working with python and jupyter notebook. I m trying to do clustering on my data set for a data set that does not have a class label. I tried a code, an I m getting a graph of k vs sum of squared distances, but I have not defined which column in my data set it has considered. In my data set there are 11 columns, so i want to know how to define which column to use, and not use all columns at once.

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(font_scale=1.2)
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

stock=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dulangi/Downloads/winequality-red.csv")

Sum_of_squared_distances = []
K = range(1,15)
for k in K:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    km = km.fit(stock)
    Sum_of_squared_distances.append(km.inertia_)

plt.plot(K, Sum_of_squared_distances, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Sum_of_squared_distances')
plt.title('Elbow Method For Optimal k')
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the columns you wish to use by a statement like this:

```
...

stock=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Dulangi/Downloads/winequality-red.csv")

Sum_of_squared_distances = []

stock = stock[["columnA", "columnB", "columnC" ]]

...
```

Obviously, you will need to substitute columnA, columnB, etc. with real columns from your dataset.